# SWF on website header

Tags: html, wordpress, flash

I have an SWF on the header section of our site. It's embedded with Kimili Wordpress Plugin:

```
<div class="swfheader">
<?php echo do_shortcode('[kml_flashembed publishmethod="static" fversion="8.0.0" movie="http://xxx/uploads/2016/Assets/header.swf" width="1950" height="270" targetclass="flashmovie" play="true" loop="true" menu="false" quality="best" scale="noscale" allowfullscreen="false" allowscriptaccess="never" allownetworking="none"]');  ?>  
</div>
```

Problem I'm having is auto play. In most browsers a "play" icon shows up for the swf to start and in other browsers everything works fine.

I used Adobe Animate CC to create it and publish settings under HTML Wrapper has only the loop option checked.

Is there any way to fix this issue? I'd like to have SWF auto play in all browsers if possible.

Comment: flash autoplay is going the way of the dinosaurs, mostly due to flash being such a ludicrously moronically insecure bug-ridden pile of crap (and I"m being politely generous by not saying what I really think). Stop using Flash, period. It's dying out, and you're not going to be able to override click-to-play anyways, because it's a SECURITY/SAFETY measure imposed by browsers.

Comment: I see. What would you recommend instead? Just need a 30 second loop animation on header. What do I create it with?

Comment: @MarcB, chillax it's friday...

Comment: use html5 video instead, maybe. there's no way to override the click-to-play thing. if there were, every malicious flash ad in the universe would be using it.

Answer (score 0):

Your banner size is triggering the browsers assumption that it's some external advert banner (those need to be "click to play" in case of some noisy data hogging video advert that no-one asked for). To avoid it, the html & swf must be in **same exact location**:

Example : 
`mysite.com/post1/page.html` and `mysite.com/post1/banner.swf`.

I don't know how you will meet that expectation via Wordpress since your posts `.html` file & your `uploads` folder content exist in two separate locations.